# Jquery post both file and data with one ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, image-uploading

Hi I have a wordpress php class that receives my ajax and works good.
Now i have to upload a file in the same POST request i use to pass parameters to the PHP class ( i have a switch in the class that sends me to the proper function based on the parameters in the POST data ).

this is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {


$('#imageUploadForm').on('submit',(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    var userID = <?php echo get_current_user_id(); ?>; 
    var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
    var data = {
            'action': 'romme_call',
            'whatever': 1234, 
            'userID': userID,
            'function_call': 'upload_profile_photo',
            **'form_data' : formData**
        };
         console.log(data);
        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            console.log("done");
            console.log(data);
        });
```

this code will of course return a "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation"

because it does not accept formData as parameter in data.

how can i handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It returns `Illegal invocation` because jQuery is trying to parse the form data with `$.param`.

When submitting files with jQuery's ajax processing must be turned off

```
$('#imageUploadForm').on('submit', (function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    var userID = <? php echo get_current_user_id(); ?> ;
    var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';

    formData.append('action', 'romme_call');
    formData.append('whatever', '1234');
    formData.append('userID', userID);
    formData.append('function_call', 'upload_profile_photo');

    $.ajax({
        url  : ajaxurl,
        type : 'POST',
        data : formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    }).done(function(response) {
        console.log("done");
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you it works very nice! I'll study the ajax processing for the next times :P